# Using rasterio to mask/crop a raster results in AttributeError

Tags: python, rasterio

I'm trying to use `rasterio` to `mask` a raster. According to the [mask documentation](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.mask.html), I need to load a raster file in 'r' mode, which I have done like so:

```
file = rasterio.open('/data/corine2018_100m/test.tif')
print(file)
<open DatasetReader name='/data/corine2018_100m/test.tif' mode='r'>
```

I also need a `shapes` which is an iterable GeoJSON-like object. I have GeoJSON serialised a Polygon object from a Django `PolygonField()` and added it to a list (my interpretation of the documentation's 'iterable object'):

```
obj = newJob.objects.create(job_loc="SRID=4326;POLYGON ((0.9063720703125029 52.32023207609735, 0.8239746093749998 52.10819209746323, 1.170043945312496 52.14191683166823, 1.170043945312496 52.31351619974807, 0.9063720703125029 52.32023207609735))")

poly = [obj.job_loc.geojson]
print(poly)
['{ "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 0.906372070312503, 52.320232076097348 ], [ 0.823974609375, 52.108192097463231 ], [ 1.170043945312496, 52.141916831668233 ], [ 1.170043945312496, 52.313516199748072 ], [ 0.906372070312503, 52.320232076097348 ] ] ] }']

print(type(poly))
<class 'list'>
```

I then attempt the mask with:

```
masked_band, masked_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(file, poly, crop=True)
```

However, I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I have tried [following this](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/issues/1343) (i.e. adding my JSON to a list) but I still get the error. Can someone help me mask this raster?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your example you have a list of a string, you need to transform the string to a dictionary, using for example json.loads(str)

If you change `poly = [obj.job_loc.geojson]` to `poly = [json.loads(obj.job_loc.geojson)]` then you will have a list of a dictionary.